# Capturar retorno de erro em função assíncrona para tratamento

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando tratar um erro de timeOut. Quando ocorresse o timeOut a aplicação deveria rodar novamente. Inicialmente esse loop deveria ser feito em um modulo externo que chamasse esse, entretanto devido as dificuldades acabei por tentar tratar ambos no mesmo arquivo.

Atualmente o código se encontra como se segue:

```
exports.acesso = function(sitepage, selector) {

    //variaveis
    const now = new Date,
        fs = require('fs'),
        Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
        nightmare = Nightmare({
            show: false,
            waitTimeout: 2
        });
    var date, result = {};

    //processo
    var processo = function() {
        nightmare.goto(sitepage)
            .wait(selector)
            .evaluate(function(selector) {
                return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
            })
            .end()
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                if (error.message === '.wait() timed out after 2msec') {
                    console.error('Error: 500');
                    console.log('tentando novamente');
                    //aqui deveria ocorrer o loop
                    //tentei com processo();
                } else {
                    console.error(error);
                    return error;
                }
            })
    }
    processo();
}
```

Comment: Deu algum erro quando usaste `processo();` dentro do `catch`?

Comment: Não, ele encerra a aplicação, mas não faz o loop

Comment: Talvez o encadeamento de promises esteja a falhar... Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/c8rsddrf/, adaptando ao teu caso terias de fazer `return nightmare.goto(sitepage) ... etc` e depois dentro do `catch` quando chamas de novo o processo fazer `return  processo();`. Testa isso.